# Is there a way to access the name of the YAML variable file passed as an argument to robot framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, robotframework

I need to automate the calling of a Python script like this:

```
python3 sendStuff.py --yaml yamlVariableFile.yaml
```

To automate this, I am using RobotFramework. I plan to call the Robot script like this:

```
robot robotScript.robot --variablefile yamlVariableFile.yaml
```

I can now access the variables specified within yamlVariableFile.yaml, but I need a way to access the name of this file as well - yamlVariableFile.yaml - since I need to pass it as an argument to the Python script - sendStuff.py - within the robot script. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can do that. What you can do is pass the file name in a separate variable (not variable file):

```
--variable filename:yamlVariableFile.yaml
```

or add an additional [variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line) to the yaml file that could have the name of the file itself.

Comment: @kruttikaSW29 Did you manage to try it out?